# How do you search only a single folder in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I want to search for files created after a certain date in **one** particular **folder**.
I"ve got the date part working right but not the "one folder" part.

I've tried using in:  and also "AND "  but it only returns the folder, not files *in* the folder.

Comment: [Google Drive search operators](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?p=empty_search_ww&rd=1) don't currently support a way to search only within a single folder. It doesn't look like you'll be able to do what you want. The best you can do is to view that folder and sort by "Last Modified".

Comment: @AlEverett, if you want to turn that into an answer, I'll mark that as correct (unless someone else comes along an finds a solution!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Drive search operators](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?p=empty_search_ww&rd=1) don't currently support a way to search only within a single folder. It doesn't look like you'll be able to do what you want.

The best you can do is to view that folder and sort by "Last Modified".